# Update configuration and restart self-hosted ASP.NET Web API 2 on HTTP request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a self-hosted OWIN web app running ASP.NET Web API 2.2, which is executed as a windows service. I want to achieve a remote configuration scenario: from a client, I want to make an HTTP request and in the called Web API action, I want to update a configuration file (e.g. to change a DB connection string) and then restart the service (so that the new configuration is loaded). However, here is the tricky part:

If I simply call `Environment.Exit`, then the respone won't finish and the client won't get the message that it worked. **Is there any way to write to the response stream and finish it before restarting the service from within a Web-API action? Or should I use something else for this, maybe a filter?** Or is there any other way that you would rather suggest?

I am not interested in any security discussion - the service is only available in an intranet and the corresponding Web API action is secured with authentication and authorization.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Restarting the service is a very heavy-handed way of solving this problem. Have you considered making your components capable of responding to configuration changes?

Comment: @PaulTurner Thanks for your response - I'm aware that your solution would be way better (reinitialize the application in the composition root) but unfortunately, I cannot do this in the amount of time I have left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look like sucker punch, but it works:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ActionMethod()
{
    var httpActionResult = Ok(); //some work instead it
    new Thread(() =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Environment.Exit(1);
    }).Start();
    return httpActionResult;
}
```

I not shure, but if you exit with exitCode != 0, then services subsystem will think, that your service crashed and try restat it (If you setup it in service settings)